# effect size for paired t test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, t-test, effect-size

I have question regarding effect size for paired t test

some textbooks and statistical software like spss use this formula

> Cohen′sd = d/SDofdifference

to calculate effect size for paired t test and other use this

> Cohen′sd  = d/SDaverage

> SDaverage = sqrt((1sd ^2 +sd^2)/2)

both give different result!

so which one should I use for paired t test? And why there are two way that give different result?

Comment: To learn more about the different choices for standardizing the mean difference $d$ of an effect, take a look at this review article: [Calculating and reporting effect sizes to facilitate cumulative science: a practical primer for t-tests and ANOVAs](https://doi.org/10.3389/fpsyg.2013.00863).

Answer (score 1):

For the paired-samples case, the most common variant of Cohen's *d* is simply the mean of the differences divided by the standard deviation of the differences.

The following can be run in R, or at [rdrr.io/snippets/](https://rdrr.io/snippets/).

(Example taken from [here](https://rcompanion.org/handbook/I_04.html), with the caveat that I wrote it.)

```
Before = c(65, 75, 86, 69, 60, 81,  88, 53, 75, 73)
After  = c(77, 98, 92, 77, 65, 77, 100, 73, 93, 75)

Difference = Before - After

mean(Difference)

   ### -10.2

sd(Difference)

   ### 8.469553

mean(Difference) / sd(Difference)

 ### -1.204314
```

Note that Cohen's *d* is negative, suggesting that the values in the second sample (*After*) are greater than those in the first sample (*Before*).

Also note that some calculators will return the absolute value of Cohen's *d*.

There are variants to this calculation.  For example, there are cases where some suggest using the standard deviation of the *Before* samples as the denominator.

It is often useful to report the confidence interval for the effect size statistic.

For R users, at the time of writing, I didn't find a package that has pre-built function to calculate the confidence interval for the paired-samples case that I like.  Below is code to get the confidence interval by bootstrap.

```
n = length(Difference)

Data = data.frame(1:n, Difference)

library(boot)

Function = function(input, index){
  Input = input[index,]
  Result = mean(Input$Difference) / sd(Input$Difference)
  return(Result)}

Boot = boot(Data,
            Function,
            R=1000)

boot.ci(Boot,
        conf = 0.95,
        type = "perc")

   ### Intervals : 
   ### Level     Percentile     
   ### 95%   (-2.358, -0.681 )
```

Comment: The metafor package provides that: `library(metafor)`, 
`dat <- escalc(measure="SMCC", m1i=mean(Before), m2i=mean(After), sd1i=sd(Before), sd2i=sd(After), ri=cor(Before,After), ni=length(Before))`, and then `summary(dat)`. Note that the usual bias correction is also applied, which is why the estimate differs from the one given above.